# uncaught exception Fuel\Core\Database_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server gone away

Tags: database, xampp, migration, fuelphp

Traying to do some migrations with fuelphp. the packages are ready to migrate and properly installed for app:defailt but dont let me conect with the database and proceed to imprement the migration. Also the port and the databse are properly cofigured for the port.

Comment: What environment are you trying to migrate? Are your configurations stored in `fuel/app/config` or are they stored within `env` directories, such as `fuel/app/config/production`?

Comment: Already solved, thanks for the comment tho !!!